# case-control matching on exact age and gender

Tags: r, match

I am doing a case-control study and I want to match cases to controls on exact age and gender in a 1:10 ratio
my case are 21 and my controls are more than 40,000

```
out <- NULL
for (i in 1: length(patient_HRV[,10]) ){
  g <-patient_HRV$SEX[i]
  y <-patient_HRV$Age[i]
  
  
  x <- sample((which(control_HRV$Sex==g & control_HRV$Age>=y-1 & control_HRV$Age<=y+1)), size=5 )
  out <- c(out, x); 
  out <- out[!duplicated(out)]
  if (duplicated(out)=="TRUE")
    i=i-1;
  out = out(size(out)-1,);
  end
}
```

I get this error

```
Error in sample.int(length(x), size, replace, prob) : 
  invalid first argument
```

my data looks like this

```
 PatientID  Age MeanRR  MeanBPM MedianRR    MedianBPM   MinRR   MinBPM  MaxRR   MaxBPM  SDNN    RMSSD   SEX
1527326001  56    1257    57.69     1452    41.32         422   40.38   1486    142.18  397.34  468 Female
1527326001  56    1257    57.69     1452    41.32         422   40.38   1486    142.18  397.34  468 Female
```

Comment: Can you show a small reproducible example

Answer (score 0):

The message means that there are no matches in `which(control_HRV$Sex==g & control_HRV$Age>=y-1 & control_HRV$Age<=y+1)`. You can't sample 5 elements from an empty population.

You get the same message from this simpler example:

```
> sample(numeric(), 5)
Error in sample.int(length(x), size, replace, prob) : 
  invalid first argument
```